# calculate $\int_o^\pi \frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2x} \,dx$

Tags: integration

Given $$I = \int\limits_0^\pi \frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2\!x}dx$$

1. prove without calculating $ \frac{\pi}{2} \le I \le \pi $
2. calulate $I$

so far I know $I = \int\limits_0^\pi \frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2\!x}dx \le \int\limits_0^\pi x\sin x =\pi$

Comment: Your thoughts? Your efforts?

Comment: Hint: integrate by parts ($I = -\int x\,d(\arctan(\cos x))$) and look at graph of $\arctan(\cos x)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$I = \int\limits_0^\pi \frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2\!x}dx\tag 1$$

Using property of definite integral $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$, we get 
$$I = \int\limits_0^\pi \frac{(\pi-x)\sin (\pi-x)}{1+\cos^2(\pi-x)}dx$$
$$I = \int\limits_0^\pi \frac{(\pi-x)\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx\tag 2$$
Now, adding (1) & (2), we get $$I+I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\pi\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx$$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx$$

$$I=-\frac{\pi}{2}\left[\tan^{-1}(\cos x)\right]_{0}^{\pi}$$
$$I=-\frac{\pi}{2}\left[\tan^{-1}(\cos \pi)-\tan^{-1}(\cos 0)\right]$$
$$I=-\frac{\pi}{2}\left[\tan^{-1}(-1)-\tan^{-1}(1)\right]$$
$$I=-\frac{\pi}{2}\left[\frac{-\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right]=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Comment: @harischandrarajppot. How would you show without calculating that it is more than half $\pi$ ?  That is also part o of question 1.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva  No. The OP was to show that without evaluating the integral.

Comment: @Shailesh: Oh, I see, misunderstood you. Indeed I had thought of commenting like you, but I desisted when the OP accepted this answer.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva. To me the problem is still not fully solved. It may be very straightforward to show the remaining part, but the answer needs to address that issue.

Comment: A more generic formula : $$\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$$

Comment: @Shailesh I do agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

$I=\int_0 ^\pi$$\frac{xsinx}{1+cos^2 x}$$dx$....(i)

$\Rightarrow I= \int_0 ^\pi \frac{(\pi-x)sinx}{1+cos^2x} dx$...(ii)

Summing (i) and (ii) we have,

$2I=\pi\int_0 ^\pi \frac{sinx}{1+cos^2x}dx$

$\Rightarrow I=\frac \pi2 \int_0 ^\pi \frac{sinx}{1+cos^2x}dx$

Now assume that $cosx=z$
$\Rightarrow -sinx=dz$

Now replace the variables and the according limits in your integral

i.e. $I= \frac \pi2 \int_0 ^\pi \frac{-z}{1+z^2}dz$

Then it is nothing difficult to find the result.